# Gremlin Emit Times Loses Lower Hop Solution (Gremlify Example Included)

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Relatively new to gremlin and working with this query:

```
g.V().or(has('LOCATION', eq('IPLTINMYGT0')),
has('LOCATION', eq('IPLTINMYK01'))).
repeat(bothE().otherV()).emit().times(1).has('LOCATION',eq('FSHRIN01K00')).dedup().
path().by(valueMap('LOCATION')).dedup()
```

And this simple graph on gremlify:
https://gremlify.com/grrlq20ig57/1

When I vary the query from times(1) to times(2), the result that shows up in the times(1) query no longer shows up in the times(2) query. I'm guessing this can be read as 'at most 1 hop' or 'at most 2 hops' so I was expecting when I went to higher level hops the times(1) result would still be included. Any way to get the times(1) result to show up (in addition to the times(2) result) when issuing times(2) queries (or greater)? Does this behavior have anything to do with DFS vs BFS? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `dedup()` after `has('LOCATION',eq('FSHRIN01K00'))` is filtering away one of the vertices emitted when you do `times(2)`. Therefore when you call `path()` it is only called once on the traverser that survives that filter. If you remove that `dedup()` you get both paths traversed.